# Putting scrollbar inside the div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put my vertical scrollbar inside my div, but I'm unable to move it

I extracted part of the code in order to avoid spam of codes. See below:

```css
 .toprightcontrols {
     margin: 0 3% 0 0;
     display: flex;
     position: absolute;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     top: 0;
     width: 150px;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 #mymenu{
    padding:10px;
    background:none;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-self:center;
    justify-self:right;
}
 #mymenu:before{
    content:url(http://127.0.0.1/img/blog/list.png);
}
 .menu-title{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
 .dropdown-toggle:after{
    display:block!important;
}
 .hr{
    margin:5px 5px 10px 5px;
}
 .country{
    background:#555;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:0.7rem;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 3px;
}


 button{
    margin:0;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    line-height:inherit;
}
 .dropdown-toggle{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
 .dropdown-toggle::after{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:.255em;
    vertical-align:.255em;
    content:"";
    border-top:.3em solid;
    border-right:.3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:.3em solid transparent;
}
 .dropdown-toggle:empty::after{
    margin-left:0;
}
 *,::after,::before{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
 hr{
    margin:1rem 0;
    color:inherit;
    background-color:currentColor;
    border:0;
    opacity:.25;
}
 hr:not([size]){
    height:1px;
}
 .dropdown-menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    z-index:1000;
    display:block;
    min-width:10rem;
    max-height:calc(4 * 200%)!important;
    padding:.5rem 0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:1rem;
    color:#212529;
    text-align:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
    background-clip:padding-box;
    border-radius:13px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
 #dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    border-radius:500px;
    background-color:rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
}
 #dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:6px;
    background-color:rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
}
 #dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    background-color:rgb(226, 209, 209);
}
 .dropdown-menu.show{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    inset:0px auto auto 0px;
    margin:0px;
    transform:translate(10px, 50.303px);
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
 .radio-label{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
 .radio-label input{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
}
 .radio-label .inner-label{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
 .radio-label .inner-label:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-bottom:1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:15px;
}
 .radio-label input:checked+.inner-label:before{
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
 .radio-label input:checked+.inner-label:after{
    content:"✓";
    color:rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.8);
    position:absolute;
    font-size:12px;
    left:5px;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toprightcontrols">
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" id ="subtitles" href="#"  id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <div class="menu-title"> <span>My list</span></div>
            <hr class="hr">
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test' checked='checked'>
                <span class="inner-label">Disabled</span>
            </label>
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test2'>
                <span class="inner-label">English <div class="english country">EN</div></span>
            </label>
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test3'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">YY</div></span>
            </label>
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test4'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test5'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test6'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
            <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test7'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The final result must be something like this =>

[image: final result]

I tried using `padding` but but got nothing different. Note that the `border-radius` must not conflict with the scrollbar.

Where am I doing wrong? Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, this is just how scrollbars work. You can adapt your design and work with a padding on top / bottom and only make the list-part scrollable. Something like this:

I added the `.menu-wrap` div, see it's CSS how this can work. I set the height of it to `100% - padding-top - padding-bottom` so it fit's into the space.

There are for sure also other ways to get this to work.

You should also clean up your HTML, it is full of errors. You have a ul without any list elements, I changed this in my code. A button with href also doesn't make sense. And a title should be a title (`h1, h2, h3...` )

```css
.toprightcontrols {
  margin: 0 3% 0 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#mymenu {
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: right;
}

#mymenu:before {
  content: url(http://127.0.0.1/img/blog/list.png);
}

.menu-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown-toggle:after {
  display: block!important;
}

.hr {
  margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.country {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 3px;
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .255em;
  vertical-align: .255em;
  content: "";
  border-top: .3em solid;
  border-right: .3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-toggle:empty::after {
  margin-left: 0;
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

hr {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border: 0;
  opacity: .25;
}

hr:not([size]) {
  height: 1px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 13px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  padding: 20px 0;    
  height: calc(4 * 200%)!important;

}

/**/
.menu-wrap {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px); /* 100% - 20px padding top - 20px padding bottom*/
}

#dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
}

#dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: rgba(162, 162, 162, 1);
}

#dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: rgb(226, 209, 209);
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: translate(10px, 50.303px);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.radio-label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.radio-label input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.radio-label .inner-label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-label .inner-label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 15px;
}

.radio-label input:checked+.inner-label:before {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.radio-label input:checked+.inner-label:after {
  content: "✓";
  color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toprightcontrols">
  <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" id="subtitles" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <div class="menu-title"> <span>My list</span></div>
      <hr class="hr">
      <div class="menu-wrap">
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test' checked='checked'>
                <span class="inner-label">Disabled</span>
            </label>
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test2'>
                <span class="inner-label">English <div class="english country">EN</div></span>
            </label>
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test3'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">YY</div></span>
            </label>
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test4'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test5'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test6'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
        <label class='radio-label'>
                <input name='ddtest' type='radio' id='test7'>
                <span class='inner-label'>French <div class="english country">XX</div></span>
            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the scrollbar isnt getting border-radius effect?

Comment: Because that's how scrollbars work.  You can't add a border-radius effect to it (at least not that I know of) Scrollbars are to help the user understand where they are, they are not meant to be styled too much. There are ways to style size / color, but some things you just can't stlye.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible, using your code, to let the scrollbar be equal to my code? (https://prnt.sc/_TqEuBqUJlTy). Changing the color and size at least

Comment: I'm trying to set the size but it's not working, idk why

Comment: You can only make it thinner: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width color is not really supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars

Comment: How isnt it supported if I make it to be colored on my post?

Comment: I was just going from the page, changing color with prefixed css seems to work. You can do it like you did it in your original post, just target the inner wrapper instead of the outer one for your scrollbars styles. I can update the snippet next week if you need it!